# What are some widely used cryptography / hash libraries in C?

Tags: c, cryptography

I've been working on cryptography implementations in C. 
I am required to use hash a message using any one of the popular hash functions like SHA,MD5, etc.

In Java, there is a security library which takes care of these things.
But how do I do the same in C?

for example:
char *str = "this is a message";
char *hash = SHA(str);

Something of this sort. It would be of great help if some one can point me to some library which has already implemented these functions which i can call for my program.

Thanks!

Comment: Must it be done in `C` and not `C++`?

Comment: Have searches led you to any relevant libraries which could be used as examples and/or to indicate prior research?

Comment: I posted the question after googling it. I was not able to find any "standard" solution to my problem. Thought Stackoverflow will give me a lot of easy and standard options! Hope I am not exploiting the site. 
@Andy: It's in C.

Comment: Which operating system?  If it's a Unix or Unix-alike, it probably already has OpenSSL installed.  Try `man 3 md5`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[sphlib](http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/) is an opensource library which provides optimized (but portable) implementations in C of many hash functions.

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is a more generic cryptographic library, which is widely deployed and provides implementations of hash functions, too (less hash functions than sphlib, but it also includes other cryptographic primitives).

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL is indeed widely available. For your example you could use

```
unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; 
char *str = "this is a string";
SHA1(str, strlen(str), digest);
```