# Crypto++ equivalent in C

Tags: c, cryptography, crypto++

Is there any equivalent of open-source ANSI-C library for cryptographic primitives.
I know about Crypto++ for C++, but was not able to find anything for C

Mostly I need SHA-1, SHA-2, AES, RSA

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some widely used cryptography / hash libraries in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637697/what-are-some-widely-used-cryptography-hash-libraries-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use OpenSSL. It may be a bit over sized for your purpose but it does contain your primitives. It is both used a lot and it is maintained.

Comment: If you don't want to take time to write an answer, then don't write it.

Comment: @owlstead Please elaborate - what's wrong with Peter's answer?

Comment: @qrdl he's probably talking about poor formating/explanation in [previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12494699/revisions).

Comment: @qrdl nothing, I even voted it up. Take a look at my edit (by clicking the part after "edited" above my sign to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: mea grande culpa. English is not my native spoken and written language. I just wanted to point the OP to openssl (not more-not less), but StackOverflow forced me to write more characters, so i filled my answer up with "smalltalk".

Comment: @owlstead. your edit has a completely different connotation. "I use..." implies, that someone (me) has actual used openssl for exactly the requested purpose. where instead "You could..." implies hear-say and i do not kwo if openssl will help for the questioner. owlstead because you changed it: what is the difference between "supported" and "maintained"?

Comment: Well, supported would imply that you would get adequate/on time responses from somebody considered part of openssl, maintained means that the software is kept up to date and bugs are solved and security fixes are released. With the current state of openssl documentation, I'm personally not so sure of the first. Finally, please try to at least capitalize your sentences and try to be objective (e.g. use "I" in comments only).

Answer (score 5):

[PolarSSL](http://polarssl.org) seems to have quite good coverage.